# How to count number of checkboxes on open object in view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to count the number of checkbox elements on the current panel I am on. What is happening is that I have checkboxes on 4 panels, on each panel there are checkboxes.
Only one panel can be open at a time. When I do a count of checkboxes, I am getting the total of all the checkboxes in my app and not the number on the panel I am showing.

I have tried specifically telling the code that this is the window open
    var a = angular.element(document.querySelector('[widget-id="popup-1"] 
      div')).scope().$parent.me.visible
but to no avail,

I am not sure how to tell the code that this is the panel that is open, count checkboxes on it only.

I am trying to count the number of boxes, then compare checked boxes and if num = checked, then I will continue on.

```
$scope.checkNum = function() {
 // var a = angular.element(document.querySelector('[widget-id="popup-1"] 
  div')).scope().$parent.me.visible
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
//or document.forms[0].elements;
var cbs = [];
//will contain all checkboxes
var checked = [];
//will contain all checked checkboxes
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
    cbs.push(inputs[i]);
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      checked.push(inputs[i]);
    }

}
}
 var nbCbs = cbs.length;
 //number of checkboxes
 var nbChecked = checked.length;
   //number of checked checkboxes
    alert("# checkboxes = " + nbCbs + "\n" +  "# checked checkboxes = " + 
    nbChecked);
    console.log(" # checked checkboxes = " + nbChecked);
}
```

Comment: Could we have your HTML code please?

Comment: please share https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Jack, I do not have the HTML as it is generated behind the scenes.
I can get you it from the developer tools -> source if that would help.

Comment: @user5451365 look at my answer and let me know if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

let's say your current panel looks like the following

```js
var test = document.getElementById("dv_Test");
get_CheckboxCount(test);
function get_CheckboxCount(element) {
  var check = element.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  console.log(check.length);
}
```

```html
<div id="dv_Test">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>

<div id="dv_Test2">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: I will check it out. Many Thanks

Comment: You can click on Run code snippet and try if it is working or not

Comment: Mumbai, the html is angularjs and I cannot figure out the id of the element the checkboxes are on...

Comment: I use one of our products that is drag and drop and you drag widgets ("panel") or ("gridlayout")  and ("checkbox") onto the canvas and then u can use Javascript to bind to these widgets..
I know, not easy...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185963/discussion-between-user5451365-and-mumbai-wadala).